# How do I use jest to test jsx components?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

According to the docs, jest can only be used to test js files. Can we use it to test the jsx? Jsx files? Can we use it to test jsx files? If so, how?

Comment: If you make a preprocessor, jest will pick up your .jsx files. Just follow the tutorial https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content

Comment: can I do 
            Test = require('../lib/components/Test.jsx'), in my jest test files?

Comment: Yes, omit the file extension and Jest will handle the rest.

Comment: also why do I have to put jest.dontMock('../src/components/Test') at the top of each test file

Comment: Because otherwise Jest will mock it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use babel-jest for testing jsx file.
Read more [at here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#babel-integration)

To run test for jsx file you need to add more .jsx when unmock or import implement code.

Example:

For Js file: jest.unmock('../jsx/CheckboxWithLabel')

For JSX file: jest.unmock('../jsx/CheckboxWithLabel.jsx')

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json add these lines:

```
"jest": {
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(js|jsx)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "jsx"]
}
```